# Reaction force to applied force in case of a spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

When we apply a force on spring and compress it then what is the reaction pair to the applied force? if it is restoring force then why it is always not equal to applied force?

Comment: The restoring force is always equal to the applied force, I believe you are talking about the displacement that the applied force results in springs with different compression constants.

Comment: @ten1o yes , if restoring force is equal to applied force  then why -kx?

Comment: That expression states that for an applied force F and compression constant k, the force can compress the spring x meters. If you apply a force of magnitude 3F to a spring, you will compress it 3x meters, and the product of k and 3x will always equal 3F.

Comment: @ten1o but applied force and restoring force are applied to same object that is spring so how  they are action reaction pair?

Comment: The restoring force is applied by the spring to the object, the object applies force to the spring. That's why a mass tied at the end of the spring speeds up when the spring is released from compression.

Comment: Not sure what your issue is but are you asking if rhe applied force equals the restoring force why does the spring compress?

Comment: @BobD my teacher said that applied force is not equal to restoring force that is why the spring compresses . so my question is related to that

Comment: The applied force is not equal to the restoring force *during the interval of time when the displacement is accelerating*  I think that's what your teacher meant.   Once the speed of displacement is constant (or zero) the two forces are equal.  What adds an additional possible point of confusion is that the applied force (and the reaction force) *increases* as the spring is compressed  *even when the speed of displacement is constant*